# Changing URL - how harmful is it

Tags: url

We have a very old site with lots and lots of content. We are considering changing our URL because the current URL was a vanity URL and does not represent the company in its current form. How

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't represent who the company as it is now then you should definitely use the new URL and have a splash page on the old URL with a link to the new website (avoid instant redirects because people may then think your new website is just spam) with a brief explanation why you are doing it and that all services on the old website are on the new one (or something alike)